# Compare object just some positions

Tags: javascript, json

I'm the newbie about javascript

```
var a = { "Q1":"a","Q2":"b","Q3":"x"};
var b = { "Q1":"a","Q2":"b","Q3":"y"};
```

I just want to compare between Q1,Q2 of a and b and return true.
Can i do like that?

Comment: Do you mean `a.Q1 == b.Q1 && a.Q2 == b.Q2`?

Comment: Please clerify your question. You've got 2 objects, `a` and `b`. Both have the properties `Q1` and `Q2` which both contain the strings `a` and `b`. You're asking to compare something here, but what are you trying to compare? Do you want to see if the properties `Q1` and `Q2` both have the same values in each object? Or do you want to see if they contain the values `a` and `b`? Or both?

Comment: As a tip for asking questions: Use a different name / value for each data type to avoid confusions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if((a.Q1 == b.Q1) && (a.Q2 == b.Q2)){
   return true;
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question at this point. It's unclear whether OP wants to compare objects or property values